# how to Query accounts in developer.salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce, crm, visualforce, force.com

i'm a salesforce newbie, so my question might be a trivial one.
I just tried the code here `http://www.tgerm.com/2011/03/javascript-remoting-jquery-templates.html`
to query  accounts from a visual force page.I just wanted to know, is there a way to query directly in the `developer.force.com` interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel like installing any software on your machine you can always use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/), (Queries -> SOQL query). It's described on http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench

Or when you're logged in to your Org check out the links in upper right corner and go to "Developer Console". But it's mostly aimed ad execution of Apex so if you want queries it won't be best match, full of assigning to Lists or calling `System.debug()`...

Comment: can i view available accounts in the GUI in develoeper.force.com without using any other tool

Comment: developer.force.com is a set of wiki-like pages and resources for devs, not bound to any particular SF instance. I don't understand your question, are you logged in to any Salesforce server? What do you mean by "developer.force.com interface". It's like asking "can I see my emails on Wikipedia".

Comment: well i just created a page in http://developer.force.com  using details from http://www.tgerm.com/2011/03/javascript-remoting-jquery-templates.html  which shows accounts on searching.Just wanted to know where these account records are coming from.I cant see those any where..

Comment: Do you mean you created this page in your "Developer Edition" (a free playground thing, http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developer_Edition?) In that case you go to https://(instance).salesforce.com/001 (replace "instance" with name of your server like "na5 or "eu1"). You can see "instance" in the address of your VF page too.